# How can I write this code in PHP

Tags: php

Hey it looks like this code is not working because its interfering with the php. Here is the code:

```
<div onclick='javascript:alert('new')'>New</div>
```

How can I write that code in PHP it seems to be messing up my php?

Answer (score 5):

The reason that it is messing things up is that the quotes around the `new` is messing up the quotes around the entire javascript.

To fix this you can try this:

```
<div onclick='javascript:alert("new")'>New</div>
```

Or you can do this:

```
<div onclick="javascript:alert('new')">New</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't, PHP is a server side language and can't respond to on page clicks that way. It's screwing up your PHP because you've screwed up the quotes

```
<div onclick='javascript:alert("new")'>New</div>
```

Comment: You can also prevent screwing up with here/now doc :)

Comment: It can be done this with ajax and lightbox ..but that's will be pretty nasty way :D